# How can write queries in MySQL that can parse JSON data in a column?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table in MySQL that has a column that store JSON objects. 
How can I easily run queries that can have some of the JSON fields in the WHERE clause?

EX: 
  With a table named `articles`

```
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | user_id | json_data                                                                                        |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |       1 | {"url":"https://www.cpubenchmark.net/","title": "CPU Benchmarks"}                                |
|  2 |       1 | {"url":"http://www.ebay.com/sch/CPUs-Processors-/164/i.html","title": "Computer and Processors"} |
|  3 |       2 | {"url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tntOCGkgt98","title": "Funny Cats Compilation"           |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to be able to write something like:

```
   SELECT user_id, json_data FROM articles WHERE json_data.title LIKE "%CPU%"
```

That should return only the first row.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670022/mysql-udf-json-extract-in-where-clause-how-to-improve-performance

Comment: Use MySQL `common_schema`

Answer (score 75):

You could use `json_extract` (5.7 up).
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract

```
SELECT user_id, json_data
FROM articles 
WHERE json_extract(json_data, '$.title') LIKE '%CPU%';
```

Comment: Is it a good idea? Make queries with json?

Comment: This answer makes more sense according to me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69523830/6668734

Comment: Can also wrap the result with `JSON_UNQUOTE` to remove double quote.

Answer (score 22):

Simple query example to extract json data,

This Will Works in MySQL AND MariaDB

1, JSON Object

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"a":1,"b":"stringdata"}','$.b');
```

output:

```
"stringdata"
```

2,JSON Objct Multi Level

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"a":1,"b":"stringdata","c":{"d":33}}','$.c.d')
```

output :

```
33
```

3, JSON Array

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[1,2,3,4]','$[0]')
```

Output:

```
1
```

4, JSON Multilevel Array

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[1,2,3,[4,5]]','$[3][1]');
```

output:

```
5
```

Comment: If I store a Dictionary in JSON, such as `[{"Key 1":5},{"Key 2":8}]` is there any way to extract the first key if I don't know its name?

Comment: Use ` JSON_KEYS()` MySQL function.

Comment: For case number 1, can also wrap the result with `JSON_UNQUOTE` to remove double quote.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up solving in this way: https://github.com/ChrisCinelli/mysql_json with a UDF. I detailed how to compile it and install it in the README. It works for me on `Ubuntu 12.04.5` on `gcc version 4.6.3` with `MySQL 5.5`

You will be able to run:

```
SELECT json_get('{"a":1}', 'a')       => 1
SELECT json_get('{"a":1}', 'b')       => NULL
SELECT json_get('[1,2,3]', 2)         => 3
SELECT json_get('{"a":[2]}', 'a', 0)  => 2

#Also:

SELECT json_get('{"a":{"b":2}}', 'a') => object
SELECT json_get('{"a":[1,2,3]}', 'a') => array

# Verify if it is a valid JSON:

SELECT ISNULL(json_get('{"a":1}'));   => 0  # Valid
SELECT ISNULL(json_get('{"a":1'));    => 1  # Invalid

# Create an example table:

CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO message (id,data) VALUES(1,'{"from":"chris","title":"Awesome Article","body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."}');
INSERT INTO message (id,data) VALUES(2,'{"from":"loren","title":"Another Article","body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."}');
INSERT INTO message (id,data) VALUES(3,'{"from":"jason","title":"How to run a query","body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."}');

# Run queries on JSON values:

SELECT json_get(data,'title') FROM message WHERE id=2;
SELECT id,data FROM message WHERE json_get(data,'from')='chris';
SELECT id,data FROM message WHERE json_get(data,'title') LIKE '%Article%';
```

Comment: Anyone know if Mariahdb supports this?

Comment: I have 5.5.14 and FUNCTION json_get does not exist

Comment: @coding-dude.com The json_get function is defined by the UDF (user-defined function) in the linked github page. It is not native to MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following query and see if it fits your needs:

```
SELECT user_id, json_data
FROM articles
WHERE common_schema.extract_json_value(json_data,'title')
LIKE "%CPU%"
```

This will only work on `MySQL` version 5.1 or newer.

Comment: We use >= 5.5. I get: `FUNCTION common_schema.extract_json_value does not exist`. I think to use that I need to install:  https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/ - I actually started looking to another plugin.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT json_extract(description, '$.contacts') AS contacts, json_extract(description, '$.name') AS name FROM `orders` WHERE 1