# How get array from json field in MySQL? Without PHP, etc ... Only in native MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have same table with json field:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `collections` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `items` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `collections` SET `id` = 1, `items`='{"0": {"id": 12967, "color": 17}, "1": {"id": 12920, "color": 69}, "2": {"id": 12310, "color": 24}, "3": {"id": 12261, "color": 17}, "4": {"id": 11874, "color": 17}}', `title`= 'First';
```

I want split items from collections and move item to new table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `collection_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `collection` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `collections_items` SET `collection`=1, `item`=12967, `color`=17;
INSERT INTO `collections_items` SET `collection`=1, `item`=12920, `color`=69;
```

Note: I don't want to use any scripts beyond MySQL (php, etc).
If I use:

```
SELECT items, JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$.*.id') ids,  JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$.*.color') colors
FROM site_catalog_collections 
WHERE id=1;
```

It return array as field:

```
ids
[12967, 12920, 12310, 12261, 11874]
colors
[17, 69, 24, 17, 17]
```

How it insert to collection_items?

Comment: Oh very nice, you have got yourself a bad table structure and now you want someone to write a stored procedure to fix it. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: All I came up with is just to write a script on php, create loop to iterate through all the data and get items array via json_deсode with the creation of the new nested loop to insert into collection_items

Comment: Have you [tried to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+read+json+data&oq=mysql+read+json+data&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3951j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Because, in that link I found [this as the third result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29138010/1155833). If yes, can you show us what you've tried? Where did it not work/go wrong? (update: found [some more JSON functions native to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html) (requires MySQL >5.7) )

Comment: All these solutions are only suitable for one-to-one, in my schema, need to select and implement one-to-many