# MySql table data to JSON Conversion

Tags: mysql, json, jsp

This is the MySql table content. How to get this result in JSON Format Using JSP.

```
                        name      child name      child name1      child color 

                        parent        null          null           null
                         null         c1                           red          
                         null                       c11            blue
                         null                       c12            red
                         null         c2                           pink     
                         null                       c21            red
                         null                       c22            red
                         null         c23                          red
```

This is my JSP CODE

```
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>


<HEAD>

    <TITLE>Fetching Data From a Database</TITLE>
  </HEAD>



    <H1>Fetching Data From a Database</H1>

    <% 
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
   ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data","root","admin321"); 


        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        String id = request.getParameter("name");  

        ResultSet resultset = 
           statement.executeQuery("select * from newnew") ; 

        if(!resultset.next()) {
            out.println("Sorry, could not find . ");
        } else {  
    %>

   <% 
       } 
   %>
   [

     <% while (resultset.next()) { %> 
     { "name": "<%= resultset.getString("name") %>" , 
     "children": [{ "name": "<%= resultset.getString
   ("child name") %>",    "color":
    "<%= resultset.getString("child color") %>" ,  "children" : [
      { "name":    "<%= resultset.getString("child name1") %>", 
      "color": "<%= resultset.getString("child color") %>"


      }
      ]}




    <% } %>
```

This shows error in the format, if i use this for another table it shows.

[{
 "name": "parent",
"children": [{
"name": "c1",
"color": "red"
 }], {
"name": "parent",
"color": "red",
  "children": [{
    "name": "c11",
"color": "red"
}]
},

}]

I want to get like this.

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"parent",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "name":"c1",
            "color":"red",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "name":"c11",
                  "color":"red"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"c12",
                  "color":"red"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "name":"c2",
            "color":"orange",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "name":"c21",
                  "color":"red"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"c22",
                  "color":"red"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"c23",
                  "color":"green"
               },
            }
         ]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most Easiest method to do this , is Use Google Json [https://github.com/google/gson] .

Or Use the Given Code (I found given code on Stackoverflow and it is useful).

```
public String getJSONFromResultSet(ResultSet rs,String keyName) {
Map json = new HashMap(); 
List list = new ArrayList();
if(rs!=null)
{
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Map<String,Object> columnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            for(int columnIndex=1;columnIndex<=metaData.getColumnCount();columnIndex++)
                String val= response.getString(metaData.getColumnName(columnIndex));
                String key = metaData.getColumnLabel(columnIndex);
                if(val== null)
                    columnMap.put(key, "");
                else if (val.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit))
                    columnMap.put(key,  Integer.parseInt(val));
                else
                    columnMap.put(key,  val);
            }
            list.add(columnMap);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    json.put(keyName, list);
 }
 return JSONValue.toJSONString(json); }
```

PS - I Used Both the method So i prefer you to Choose Google JSON .

Comment: any other way through mysql

Comment: i mean using mysql and jsp

Comment: You want to store data in Json ? if Yes than Use 2nd method and write code in Declaration tag . or Simply make a Servlet for this .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137915/how-can-write-queries-in-mysql-that-can-parse-json-data-in-a-column.      in this link i found that the json format for particular id is stored directly into the row..i am using utf8 words...is it possible to store 25,000 columns each row with 2000 characters