# Use LIKE statement in a json type column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have a table with some columns arraged kinda like this:

```
Column a (type: INT)
Column b (type: TINYINT)
Column c (type: INT)
Column d (type: TEXT)
Column e (type: JSON)
```

I want to retrieve columns `a` `b` and `c` where the column `e` has the value `x` somewhere in the list.
I'm using this command: `SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE e LIKE x;` The problem is even if the value is there, the result from this query is `[]`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Made it work by going to this thread: [How can write queries in MySQL that can parse JSON data in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137915/how-can-write-queries-in-mysql-that-can-parse-json-data-in-a-column)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137915/how-can-write-queries-in-mysql-that-can-parse-json-data-in-a-column

Comment: what kind of x values are you searching for?  what is the structure in the json?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract

Comment: Show some example data, and actual query *(with an actual value for `x`)* and the actual results you get.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GzZgVg5