# How can I remove string from json coulmn

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 600 rows in a table called `areas` contains three things `id, name, created_at` name column has like this:

```
{"ar": "سفين", "en": "Safeen"}
{"ar": "شورش", "en": "Shorsh"}
.....
```

I want to keep just the name of ar and remove anything else:

`{"ar": "سفين", "en": "Safeen"} => سفين`

Is there any query to do such a thing?

My DB is MYSQL

Comment: You have to specify whether it's SQL or MySQL (in the tags)

Comment: @Ergis Mysql as DB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can write queries in MySQL that can parse JSON data in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137915/how-can-write-queries-in-mysql-that-can-parse-json-data-in-a-column)

Comment: @JeffHolt I already saw this solution but it is not what I need. I need to trim the JSON and just keep the ar name and remove anything else and of course, I've changed the type of column to varchar(255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON_ExTRAC`

Also Bill Karmin mentioned to get rid of the Quotes around the text you can use `JSON_UNQUOTE`

And as he mentioned these function only are available since MySQL 5.7

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(tx  TEXT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('{"ar": "سفين", "en": "Safeen"}'),('{"ar": "شورش", "en": "Shorsh"}')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE mytable SET tx =  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(tx, '$.ar'))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> | tx       |
> | :------- |
> | سفين |
> | شورش |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd4c7d4fcd00b39b29305172fa6c2231)*

Comment: You may want to use [JSON_UNQUOTE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) too. And note that these functions require MySQL 5.7 or later.

Comment: thx i added the information

Comment: `UPDATE mytable SET tx =  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(tx, '$.ar'))` worked perfeclty thanks

Comment: @ser -1 for you. This was literally in the first answer of the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137915/how-can-write-queries-in-mysql-that-can-parse-json-data-in-a-column) you said was unhelpful (minus the `JSON_UNQUOTE` part).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT name.ar FROM areas
```

If you have defined `name` as a `JSON` data type

Comment: I need to trim the JSON and just keep the ar name and remove anything else and of course, I've changed the type of column to varchar(255) –

Comment: The result of `SELECT id, name.ar, created_at FROM areas` is the table you need

Comment: @jbosch Where are you getting that syntax? It does not work in MySQL for querying fields of a JSON document.